# Query not working as expected

Tags: sql, mysql

**Goal**

Select distinct ids from blog_news where

- active = 1
- title is not empty
- has at least one picture unless picture is logo, or at least one video

**The statement so far**

```
select distinct n.id from blog_news n 
left join blog_pics p ON n.id = p.blogid and active = '1' and trim(n.title) != '' 
left join blog_vdos v ON n.id = v.blogid 
where (p.islogo = '0' and p.id is not null) OR (v.id is not null)
order by `newsdate` desc, `createdate` desc
```

**The issue**

- selects blog_news ids that have pictures, unless they're logos [correct]
- selects blog_news ids that have both videos and pictures [correct]
- **does not select blog_news ids that have only videos [wrong]**

Comment: @Bugai13 Why? `IS [NOT] NULL` is standard ANSI SQL

Comment: How many % of blog_news rows satisfy (active = 1 and title is non-empty)? How many blog_news rows have at least 1 video? How many blog_news rows have at least 1 picture? And finally, how many rows in blog_pics have is_logo = 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id
  FROM blog_news n
 WHERE n.active = '1'
       AND trim(n.title) != ''
       AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM blog_pics p
                     WHERE p.blogid = n.id
                       AND p.islogo = 0)
            OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM blog_vdos v
                        WHERE v.blogid = n.id)
           )
ORDER BY n.newsdate desc, n.createdate desc
```

Where you are just interested in the existence (or not) of child rows then it is often clearer and easier to use EXISTS.

Comment: Is this efficient ? I think the sub queries need to be executed foreach row in blog_news !!! (only for rows that satisfy the active and trim(n.title) conditions respectively)

Comment: @gAMBOOKa Why avoid the subqueries, they are clear and performant.

Comment: @Vojta This far more efficient than using an IN operation like in your statement, where a whole bunch of unnecessary rows are queried to populate the IN clause. With EXISTS, the optimiser recognises the need for a simple EXISTence check.

Comment: @Tom: Your query appears to be more efficient than Vojta. His' completes in .8s, while yours completes in .4s. But we could potentially have over 50,000 rows in blog_news, right now we only have a test data of 2,000. Subqueries will really slow this down then, right?

Comment: +1 @Tom: could you explain bit more for me, how optimiser does that ? Because for me it looks like you need to execute the sub queries for any row in blog_news. I know that using IN is far from perfect, but my subqueries need to be execute just once and they could access only index (if you put index on islogo). Thanks a lot...

Comment: @gAMBOOKa Provided there is an index on blog_pics.blogid and blog_vdos.blogid, which there should be given that they are foreign keys, then the subqueries should run fast even for many rows. In fact, it is probably the trim(n.title) != '' that will slow you down.

Comment: @Vojta Your IN clause must be built up in its entirety, and hence must access all of the matching rows on the child tables. By using EXISTS, only one matching row need be found, with the rest ignored. Finding a single matching row using its foreign key index is very quick, even when performed multiple times.

Comment: +1. I generated a database of 200,000 entries in blog_news. 1% (2,000) rows have active = 1. I also generated 120,000 blog_pics with rougly 50% islogo=1. Finally, I generated 70,000 blog_vdos. Toms query runs in 0,02 sec returning ~600 entries.

Comment: @Tom: there was no index on blogids, now that there is, this is near instant. Thanks! @Ronnis: Thanks for taking the time to test it out. @Vojta: Thank you too, looks like you learned something new as well today.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem in your query.

I expect `active` is column in `blog_news` table, you should call it `n.active`. If this column is in `blog_pics` table, then this is the problem.

I would add the condition (n.active, n.title) to WHERE, as it's not related to left join (blog_pics) - but that's just for better readability, the result would be the same.

You can write the query using sub selects as well:

```
SELECT n.id FROM blog_news n
WHERE n.active = 1 AND TRIM(n.title) != '' AND n.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT p.blogid FROM blog_pics p WHERE p.islogo = 0 UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT v.blogid FROM blog_vdos
);
```

Comment: The use of IN like this is very inefficient.